# How to add AVAudioUnitVarispeed to a working AVAudioEngine which plays multiple sounds simultaneously

Tags: avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I´m making a music app for iOS. I want to play 5 files simultaneously. This already works with help of this thread: [How to play multiple sounds from buffer simultaneously using nodes connected to AVAudioEngine's mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343150/how-to-play-multiple-sounds-from-buffer-simultaneously-using-nodes-connected-to/57344229#57344229)

Now I need to play all the files a little faster using AVAudioUnitVarispeed. 
I cannot get this to work.

Here is the code:

```
import AVFoundation

class Audio {

    // MARK: AUDIO VARIABLEN
    var engineFirst: AVAudioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    var audioFilePlayer = [AVAudioPlayerNode]()
    var noteFilePath = [String]()

    // Speed
    var speedControl = [AVAudioUnitVarispeed]()

    var noteFileURL = [URL]()
    var noteAudioFile = [AVAudioFile]()
    var noteAudioFileBuffer = [AVAudioPCMBuffer]()
    let tonAnzahl = 5
    let latency = 0.03
    var playing = false

    // MARK: PLAY SOUND
    func playSound() {
        playing = true
        for i in 0...tonAnzahl - 1 {
            audioFilePlayer[i].scheduleBuffer(noteAudioFileBuffer[i], at: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            audioFilePlayer[i].play()
        }

    }

    // MARK: STOP SOUND
    func stopSound() {
        playing = false
        for i in 0...tonAnzahl - 1 {
            audioFilePlayer[i].volume = 0
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + latency, execute: {
            for i in 0...self.tonAnzahl - 1 {
                self.audioFilePlayer[i].stop()
            }
        })
    }

    // MARK: SETUP AUDIO ENGINE
    func setupAudioEngine(bassFile: String, terzFile: String, septimeFile: String, tensionOneFile: String, tensionTwoFile: String) {
        do {
            noteAudioFile.removeAll()
            noteFileURL.removeAll()
            // For each note, read the note URL into an AVAudioFile,
            // setup the AVAudioPCMBuffer using data read from the file,
            // and read the AVAudioFile into the corresponding buffer
            for i in 0...tonAnzahl - 1 {
                noteFilePath = [
                    Bundle.main.path(forResource: bassFile, ofType: "mp3")!,
                    Bundle.main.path(forResource: terzFile, ofType: "mp3")!,
                    Bundle.main.path(forResource: septimeFile, ofType: "mp3")!,
                    Bundle.main.path(forResource: tensionOneFile, ofType: "mp3")!,
                    Bundle.main.path(forResource: tensionTwoFile, ofType: "mp3")!]
                noteFileURL.append(URL(fileURLWithPath: noteFilePath[i]))

                try noteAudioFile.append(AVAudioFile(forReading: noteFileURL[i]))

                let noteAudioFormat = noteAudioFile[i].processingFormat
                let noteAudioFrameCount = UInt32(noteAudioFile[i].length)
                noteAudioFileBuffer.append(AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: noteAudioFormat, frameCapacity: noteAudioFrameCount)!)

                try noteAudioFile[i].read(into: noteAudioFileBuffer[i])
            }
            // For each note, attach the corresponding node to the engineFirst, and connect the node to the engineFirst's mixer.
            for i in 0...tonAnzahl - 1 {
                audioFilePlayer.append(AVAudioPlayerNode())
                engineFirst.attach(audioFilePlayer[i])


                // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                speedControl.append(AVAudioUnitVarispeed())
                speedControl[i].rate = 2
                engineFirst.attach(speedControl[i])

                engineFirst.connect(audioFilePlayer[i], to: speedControl[i], fromBus: 0, toBus: i, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[i].format)
                engineFirst.connect(speedControl[i], to: engineFirst.mainMixerNode, fromBus: 0, toBus: i, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[i].format)

            }

            // Audio Engine Start
            try engineFirst.start()

            // Setup the audio session to play sound in the app, and activate the audio session
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.soloAmbient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

This code plays 5 notes simultaneously if I replace

```
// HERE IS THE PROBLEM
speedControl.append(AVAudioUnitVarispeed())
speedControl[i].rate = 2
engineFirst.attach(speedControl[i])

engineFirst.connect(audioFilePlayer[i], to: speedControl[i], fromBus: 0, toBus: i, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[i].format)
engineFirst.connect(speedControl[i], to: engineFirst.mainMixerNode, fromBus: 0, toBus: i, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[i].format)
```

with

```
engineFirst.connect(audioFilePlayer[i], to: engineFirst.mainMixerNode, fromBus: 0, toBus: i, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[i].format)
```

... and call playSound().

But then I don't have the AVAudioUnitVarispeed (speedControl) implemented...

So, how to add the code for AVAudioUnitVarispeed?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with this also. 
First of all I see you are trying to connect your `audioFilePlayers` to several busses of the `AVAudioUnitVarispeed`. I'm not sure if this will work since all the different speedControls will get different inputs and output to a different bus. Busses are meant to split the Source signal to a different path. For example if you want your audio to output to the mainMixerNode, but also make a detour (ie using another bus as output) to for example a Reverb effect and then on to the mainMixerNode. 
You can try to connect all the `audioFilePlayers` to bus 0 of the `speedControl`, and then connect all `speedControl`  to bus 0...i of the `.mainMixerNode`. See if that works. 
Alternatively, if you want the speed changes to occur on all your tracks, you can make `speedControl` a master effect.
so you would do something like :

```
engineFirst.connect(audioFilePlayer[i], to: engineFirst.mainMixerNode, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[i].format)  

// And then put this outside of the loop to connect all audioFilePlayers

engineFirst.connect(engineFirst.mainMixerNode, to: speedControl, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[0].format)
engineFirst.connect(speedcontrol, to: engineFirst.outputNode, format: noteAudioFileBuffer[0].format)
```

This way you will only need one instance of `AVAudioUnitVarispeed` and you don't have to change the speed for each player seperately.

Or you could try to connect all the audioFilePlayers to bus 0...i of a single speedControl and connect speedControl to bus 0...i of the mainMixerNode.

Hope this works for you.